Spring REST X509 Certificate based Authentication
I am trying to implement X509 certificate based Authentication. Currently testing locally without a cert and also with a sample cert. However it fails with 401.
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.ANY)
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Slf4j
@Order(1)
public class X509WebFluxSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                authentication -> {
                    log.debug("Authentication attempt with: {}", authentication);
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true); // Allow all requests for testing
                    log.info("Authentication successful for: {}", authentication.getName());
                    return Mono.just(authentication);
                };

        http.x509(x509 -> x509
                        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
}
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class NettyServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> nettyCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.addServerCustomizers(this::customizeServer);
    }

    private HttpServer customizeServer(HttpServer httpServer) {
        try {
            SslContext sslContext = getServerSslContext();
            return httpServer
                    .secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(sslContext))
                    .doOnConnection(conn -> conn
                            .addHandlerFirst(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                            .addHandlerFirst(new LoggingHandler("SSL", LogLevel.INFO))
                    ).
                    handle((request, response) -> {
                        log.info("Received request: URI = {}, Method = {}", request.uri(), request.method().name());
                        return response.send(); 
                    });
        } catch (SSLException | SocketEndpointAddressException | X509SourceException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error configuring SSL context", e);
        }
    }

    private SslContext getServerSslContext()
            throws SSLException, SocketEndpointAddressException, X509SourceException {
        X509Source x509Source = X509SourceSingletonWrapper.getInstance().getX509Source();
        return SslContextBuilder.forServer(new SpiffeKeyManager(x509Source))
                .trustManager(x509Source.getX509Svid().getChainArray())
                .clientAuth(ClientAuth.OPTIONAL) //tested with NONE as well, not working
                .build();
    }
}
@GetMapping("/hello")
public Mono<String> hellod() {
    return Mono.just("Hello");
}

However, it works when I allow all requests using SecurityFilterChain.
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfigurationDev {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Configuring security for all requests");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize ->
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers("/health")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated());
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.getOrBuild();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/**");
    }
}

I believe that my Controller is a WebFlux, and ideally should call SecurityWebFilterChain. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
